# access only part of a text area javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a text area for a game that tells the player where they move to and what they see, but it also has to be able to accept input, like if the player types 'n' they should go north. How can a text area be used in this way? (That is, be used for displaying information to the player and being able to accept input from the player to execute a command).

Comment: Why does it have to serve both functions? Why not just have two separate?

Comment: While I question the design, you should be able to do this by listening to mouse events (keyup)

Answer (score 0):

Use keybindings on the entire document object so that they don't even need to type into the text area. It is easy to set your document to perform a function when the user types 'n', for example with this code:

http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/keybindings.html

For illustration, type `onPressN` as the function's name and type 'n' as the modifier key, and it will generate this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="keybindings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
sbindings = 'onPressN=110 0 0 0';
loadbindings();
</script>
```

Include the `keybindings.js` script in your web page and the above code, and then the `onPressN` function will be executed when the user types `n`, with no need for them to use the textarea at all.

Answer (score 0):

possibly do this via adding key binding on the textarea.

so `

$('textarea').keydown(function(e){

```
if(e.keyCode == '78'){
    $(this).text("Player pressed N!!")    
} else {
    $(this).text("Player didnt press N")    
}
```

});`

http://jsfiddle.net/BKM7e/